# Error Handling If

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm writing the following code and I'm trying not to add `' '` (a single space character) to my dictionary. I thought the following would work for my function. Do I need to write a more in-depth try and except statement? I get a KeyError when I run the code as is.

```
score = {"a": 1, "c":3, "b":3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, "f": 4, "i" : 1, "h" : 4, "k": 5, "j" : 8, "m": 3, "l":1, "o": 1, "n":1,
 "q":10, "p": 3, "s": 1, "r": 1, "u":1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4,"y": 4, "x": 8, "z": 10,}

def scrabble_score(word):
    total = 0 
    for i in word:
        total += score[i.lower()]
        if i == ' ':
            continue
    return total

print scrabble_score('ten')
print scrabble_score('i like chicken')
```

Comment: You should probably move the `if i == ' ':` condition above `total += score[i.lower()]`.

Comment: I think Ashwini is right. You evaluate the character before you check whether it is a space. And as it is not a key in your dictionary, you get a key error. The continue statement has no effect, as it is the last statement in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it would be better to ignore any char that is not in the table, not just spaces.

For this you can use

```
for c in word:
    total += score.get(c, 0)
```

the second parameter of `dict.get` is the value to use if the value is not present in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the if-statement with the previous line:

```
    total += score[i.lower()]
    if i == ' ':
        continue
```

Id est, use:

```
    if i == ' ':
        continue
    total += score[i.lower()]
```

edit: removed wrong explanation, see comments.

Comment: Christian is correct.  The `KeyError` is from accessing the dictionary with ' ' which is not present in the dictionary.  lowercasing whitespace would not cause a `KeyError`.

Comment: Why would lowercasing a space raise a KeyError?